# Do web.xml files need to throw an exception type for error pages

Tags: java, xml, spring, jakarta-ee

I am just wondering if using the `<exception-type>` tag is really needed within an `<error-page>` tag of web.xml files.

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

as opposed to simply having the `<error-code>` tag like below.

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed. If you dont have an exception typed error page all of your Exceptions will be serverd by

```
<error-code> 500 </error-code>
```

But if you have your own AbstractException for example MyApplicationException and you want to log this in a different way you can use `<exception-type>`.

Comment: Yea fortify was complaining that it  can be a security issue: "A web application must define a default error page for java.lang.Throwable to handle any uncaught exceptions in order to
prevent attackers from mining information from the application container's built-in error response." So even if it is not needed is it a "best practice" type of thing?